# Let $ n \geq 2 $ and $ c \geq 0 $. Show that $ A = \{x \in \mathbb {R ^ n}: \| x \|> c\} $ is connected.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $ n \geq 2 $ and $ c \geq 0 $. Show that $ A = \{x \in \mathbb {R ^ n}: \| x \|> c\} $ is connected.

I tried to make a test assuming that $A$ is written as a union of separate sets, but I haven't had a contradiction yet. I would like to know if there is another simpler way to address this problem.

Comment: What does it mean for something to be *related*?

Comment: Do you mean, “Show that $A$ is connected”?

Comment: Assuming you mean "connected" as @Joe surmises, the easiest way I see is simply to prove any two points of $A$ are path-connected.  A path-connected set is necessarily connected (although the converse doesn't necessarily hold).

Comment: Exactly, I must show that A is connected.

Answer (score 0):

ΗΙΝΤ

Since we are in $\Bbb{R}^d$ prove that $A$ is path connected.

Note that $A$ is open so if $x,y \in A$ you can find two small closed disjoint balls $\bar{B}(x,r_1),\bar{B}(y,r_2) \subseteq A$

Prove that $\{tx+(1-t)y:t \in (0,1)\} \subseteq A$